# Visual Studio Community 2013 Graphics Debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx-10

I wrote a desktop app in Visual Studio 2013 Community, the one that just came out and I am trying to use the graphics debugger. The problem I am having is that when I start up the debugger the program, the program never gets to the first frame, it only shows a white screen. Also, there is no output to the debugging interfaces. The program runs fine and the DirectX10 Graphics work fine when I do not use the graphics debugger. I have tried setting the compiler to mixed and that didn't seem to change anything. I also searched around for locale issues as I found that could be a possible issue but it didn't seem to make a difference either. Any ideas on what I need to change or setup or fix?

**EDIT**

It worked correctly one time but I am having trouble getting it to work again. The message in the diagnostics hub is: Profiling of 'Graphics Frame Capture' started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but looks like VS 2013 Community doesn't support graphics debugging, assuming this article is up to date: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873207.aspx

Comment: I believe that refers to the regular vs 2013. The community edition came out in the end of last year. It doesn't seem to be a support issue either because it works like every hundred times I try it.